# IHTMLDocument3 of all tabs

Tags: c++, com, iwebbrowser2, ihtmldocument2

My aim is to get a IHTMLDocument3 interface of each tab opened in the same internet explorer window, in order to fill out some forms.

What I've done until now: I assign a IWebBrowser2 interface to the variable "iweb". I then use "iweb" to navigate to several URLs by opening for each URL a new tab (using the "navOpenInNewTab"-FLAG):

```
HRESULT hret=idis->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2,reinterpret_cast<void**>(&iweb));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hret));

V_I4(&vFlags) = 0x0800; //navOpenInNewTabs

hr=iweb->Navigate(bstrURL1, &vFlags, &vEmpty, &vPostData, &vHeaders);
hr=iweb->Navigate(bstrURL2, &vFlags, &vEmpty, &vPostData, &vHeaders);
```

This works fine until here. But: **How can I extract the IHTMLDocument3-interfaces of each tab?** When I try to use the iweb->get_Document(...) method, I always get the document of the first tab only. I want to get the IHTMLDocument3 of all tabs that I just created, not only of the first tab. How would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `NewWindow3` event for your `IWebBrowser2`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet. Do you have an example of how I can do this?

Comment: Threre must be quite enough samples and tutorials about connection points and implementing event dispatch interfaces, even better if you're using ATL.  What you need to know here is that this event is fired for each new window coming out of one you already control.

Comment: Okay, in fact I'd like to try getting to a solution without ATL. I found a possible way to do this: The interaction accessibility class. It is not well documented though, what means that you have to undergo a trial and error-procedure in order to make it work. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/03a8c835-e9e4-405b-8345-6c3d36bc8941/ie7-ie8-tab-interaction-accessibility-class?forum=ieextensiondevelopment